# Google Calendar PHP API, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: php, google-api-php-client

```
<?php
   session_start();

   require_once "Google/Client.php";
   require_once "Google/Service/Calendar.php";

   $apiClient = new Google_Client();
   $apiClient->setApplicationName("My Application");
   $apiClient->setDeveloperKey("API_KEY");

   $service = new Google_Service_Calendar($apiClient);

   $event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event();
   $event->setSummary('Appointment');
   $event->setLocation('Somewhere');
   $start = new Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime();
   $start->setDateTime('2011-06-03T10:00:00.000-07:00');
   $start->setTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles');
   $event->setStart($start);
   $end = new Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime();
   $end->setDateTime('2011-06-03T10:25:00.000-07:00');
   $end->setTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles');
   $event->setEnd($end);
   $attendee1 = new Google_Service_Calendar_EventAttendee();
   $attendee1->setEmail('EMAIL');
   $attendees = array($attendee1,
       // ...
   );
   $event->setAttendees($attendees);
   $recurringEvent = $service->events->insert('primary', $event);


   echo $recurringEvent->getId();
?>
```

Everything compiles correctly until I execute $service->events->insert? am I authenticating wrong? I have been trying this for days. Alls I'm trying to do is simply authenticate, and create a calendar event. (I don't need multi-user auth, just one admin user).

Help is appreciated!

Comment: What error are you getting with insert? You haven't posted the authentication code where are you handling that?

Comment: @DaImTo I'm not very sure how to do it, I'm also not getting any error.